# Error following Netbeans basic tutorial of JNI

Tags: java, c, netbeans, java-native-interface

I'm following this [Netbeans tutorial for JNI](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/beginning-jni-linux.html) but when I build my `JNIDemo.c` library I get this error in the Netbeans output:

```
    "/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .clean-conf
    make[1]: Entering directory `/home/username/Documents/JavaProjects/JNIDemoCd1'
    rm -f -r build/Debug
    rm -f dist/libJNIDemoCdl.so
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/username/Documents/JavaProjects/JNIDemoCd1'

    CLEAN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 54ms)
    "/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
    make[1]: Entering directory `/home/username/Documents/JavaProjects/JNIDemoCd1'
    "/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/libJNIDemoCdl.so
    make[2]: Entering directory `/home/username/Documents/JavaProjects/JNIDemoCd1'
    mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86
    rm -f "build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/JNIDemo.o.d"
    gcc -shared -m32   -c -g -I/opt/jdk1.7.0_67/include -I/opt/jdk1.7.0_67/include/linux -include /opt/jdk1.7.0_67/include -include /opt/jdk1.7.0_67/include/linux -fPIC  -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/JNIDemo.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/JNIDemo.o JNIDemo.c
    In file included from <command-line>:0:0:
    /usr/include/stdc-predef.h:59:1: fatal error: /opt/jdk1.7.0_67/include: No such file or directory
     #endif
     ^
    compilation terminated.
    make[2]: *** [build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/JNIDemo.o] Error 1
    make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/username/Documents/JavaProjects/JNIDemoCd1'
    make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/username/Documents/JavaProjects/JNIDemoCd1'
    make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

    BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 119ms)
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: where have you installed jdk1.7_0_67?

Comment: How can I know that? I mean, according to me, it is in /opt/jdk...

Comment: according to the article you posted, it is /home/ubuntu. why did you change this if you don't know where it is? The article clearly explained the prerequisites.

Comment: I didn't changed it, I had java installed before start the tutorial and I haven't any user "ubuntu" in my home directory. In the other hand, in fact, I do have a folder "/opt/jdk1.7.0_67/include" with all the files.

Comment: The *gcc* `-include` option names a file, not a directory. Where did that come from?

Comment: It should come from the IDE, the tutorial says I must add some paths in "include directories" and "include headers" in the project properties. This is my IDE window: [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pl50wv9tabtbxzx/jni.png?dl=0).

I feel the problem is over there, as you @EJP say, `-include` is for files, so, maybe one of that fields is for files an the other is for folders, if you can see, my version is slightly different than [the tutorial one](https://netbeans.org/images_www/articles/74/cnd/beginning-jni-linux/jni-include-directories.png).

Comment: that is not what he said. the -include tell the compiler to use the given value as an include file. passing a path makes no sense, so outcome depnds on how gcc handles it. I assumed it ignores it as you have already included the paths with -I. Try to remove those bits (`-include /opt/jdk1.7.0_67/include -include /opt/jdk1.7.0_67/include/linux`) from  the make file

Comment: The error is clearly telling you it cannot manage the include files as configured, so we are trying to work out how to change the configuration properly.

Comment: Right @CharlieS , In fact, now I can see that the field "include headers" in the GUI expect to receive a file (the header), because if I set a file path there, Netbeans output says `gcc ... -include filepath ...`.
I have tried with that empty, so it ignore the `-include`, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: you do not need to include a file there. you do not have additional headers to pre-compile.

Comment: Empty doesn't work either, this is the output:<br/>
`gcc -shared -m32   -c -g -I/opt/jdk1.7.0_67/include -I/opt/jdk1.7.0_67/include/linux -fPIC  -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/JNIDemo.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/JNIDemo.o JNIDemo.c`<br/>
`In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:27:0,`<br/>
`from /opt/jdk1.7.0_67/include/jni.h:39,`<br/>
`from JNIDemo.c:1:`<br/>
`/usr/include/features.h:374:25: fatal error: sys/cdefs.h: No such file or directory`<br/>
`#  include <sys/cdefs.h>`<br/>
`compilation terminated.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!!
It was an issue with architectures.

I compiled the library with the option `-m32` in the C project properties as the tutorial says, but my virtual machine is a 64 bits machine, so I must use `-m64`.

What does it implies? when someone is working with JNI, it is necessary to match the architecture of our VM with the architecture of the library.

How to check the architecture of our library?
In the linux terminal, type:
 `objdump -f my_lib.so | grep ^architecture`.

With that you can get something like that (x32): `architecture: i386, flags 0x00000150:`
Or like this (x64): `architecture: i386:x86-64, flags 0x00000150:`

So, I put `-m64` instead of `-m32` in the properties and "et voilà!", VM 64 bits and library 64 bits working together. Thanks to all.